# ¿Insertar texto en input text en otra web con php?

Tags: php

¿Como puedo insertar texto en input text de otra web con php?
¿Como puedo presionar un botón de otra web con php?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberías decir si es una página de tu propiedad o no porque si es de tu propiedad puedes implementarle una api

Comment: no es de mi propiedad

Comment: Si sabes el nombre de cada `input`, el método en que se envían los datos (eg: GET o POST) y la `URL` a la que se envían, puedes usar [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php). Ten en cuenta que si la web fue bien diseñada, te va a costar bastante resolver todos lo problemas que van a surgir. Posiblemente `same origin request`, `cookie validation`, `hidden fields`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1: Si eres propietario de la web y nos encontramos en un formulario por ejemplo, puedes llamar el método POST agregando las variables correspondientes, en este caso usando la respuesta 2. Alternativamente puedes usar GET simplemente llamando la url desde la respuesta 2.

Si tu formulario a enviar es ejemplo.com/registrar?username=foo

Simplemente llamas esa url desde Curl.

2: Puedes usar Curl para PHP, te permite consumir datos desde urls y luego procesarlos en tu servidor.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

En ese ejemplo sencillo la respuesta del sitio es guardada en un archivo .txt, además puedes hacer click en un boton como dices, con solo llamar a curl_init junto a la url de la acción que genera/realiza el botón.

Saludos.

Comment: no quiero guardar el contenido en un fichero de texto, quiero introducir texto en la pagina web que no es de mi propiedad (en un <input type="text">) y presionar un botón, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Como te comenté, "emular" la interaccion de un usuario se realiza con Curl, no vas a poder "rellenar" de una manera simple un input. Ten en cuenta este escenario: Si tienes una pestaña donde se aprecia el input y quieres que aparezca magicamente contenido en él, debes crear un setinterval en ajax que revise peticiones en el servidor para así saber cuando hay y que hay que colocar en el input. Un poco más de información sobre el contexto ayudaría. Saludos.

Comment: Podrías comentar el código 2. Gracias por todo.